# how to hide a Pannable scrollbar in javaFX?

Tags: javafx

I created a Pannable ScrollPane . now i want to hide the bar in the right side of my scrollbar 
i use this but nothing happen

```
 .scroll-bar:horizontal .increment-arrow,
 .scroll-bar:horizontal .decrement-arrow,
 .scroll-bar:horizontal .increment-button,
 .scroll-bar:horizontal .decrement-button {
    -fx-padding:0;
    -fx-opacity: 0;
}
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I found my answer:

```
scrollPane.setHbarPolicy(ScrollBarPolicy.NEVER);
scrollPane.setVbarPolicy(ScrollBarPolicy.NEVER);
```